# Selenium get value of hidden element

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I have the below website.
shorturl.at/glJ03

I need to select the value of

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTI2MjM..."
```

But since its hidden is there way to get the value

/wEPDwUKLTI2MjM... using css path expression ?

Finally Managed to do it like this.

```
result = driver.execute_script("var value = document.querySelector('#__VIEWSTATE').value; return value;")
```

Not sure this is the best way but it works for now.

Thanks PCalkins.

I was able to do this

```
expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located('#__VIEWSTATE')                               
<selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located at 0x16739560670>
```

But still unclear on how do i get the value of the attribute value ?

Comment: You can get attribute value of even hidden element

Comment: Thanks JaSON for taking a look at this.Do you have a example for it ?

Comment: wow a negative vote already :) I don't even know what to try here but :)

Comment: Example of what? I can assure you that if you've selected correct element (even hidden) you can extract attribute value. So it doesn't really matters weather it's hidden or not

Comment: Since i am not able to target the input element as it is hidden I am unable to extract the value of viewstate.So would be kind enough to share the trick on extracting the value of viewstate here.

Comment: What do you mean by *"...not able to target the input element as it is hidden"*? Show your code and exception trace

Comment: If using webdriverwait with expected condition use presenceOfElementLocated as your condition.  That will check if the element is present, but not necessarily visible.  You can then use getAttribute("value") on the element to get the value attribute.